# JAXB @XmlRootElement with the same name

Tags: java, jaxb, classcastexception, jaxb2

I have a very long XML like :

```
<Author>
    <id></id>
    <name></name>
    <title></title>
    <address></address>
     ....
</Author>
```

I'm using JAXB to parser the XML before.

```
JAXBContext.newInstance(Author.class);
```

And my Author.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Author")
public class Author {
     private String id;
     private String name;
     private String title;
     private String address;
     ...
}
```

It works well but I don't want to parser the whole XML to a big Java bean every time.

So, I want to using below way:

Create Commentator.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Author")
public class Commentator {
     private String id;
     private String name;
     // setters, getters
}
```

Create Analyst.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Author")
public class Analyst {
     private String title;
     private String address;
     // setters, getters
}
```

And I write below code to test.

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Analyst.class, Commentator.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
String xml = "<Author> <id>1</id> <name>A</name> <title>B</title> <address>C</address></Author>";
Commentator obj = (Commentator) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));
System.out.println(obj);
```

It will print the correct reslult.

If I want to get the Analyst.

```
Analyst a = (Analyst) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));
```

I will get the Exception: `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.xxx.Commentator cannot be cast to com.xxx.Analyst`

I'm not sure this way is correct to parser. But I really need such a func.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it is a somewhat clumsy design to have several Java classes mapped
with the same `@XmlRootElement`.
But nevertheless, you are still able to achieve what you want.

You need different `JAXBContext`s for `Analyst` and `Commentator`.
And because a `JAXBContext` is a big object and `JAXBContext.newInstance(...)` takes quite a long time to execute,
it makes sense to save these `JAXBContext` instances in `static`variables
and reuse these instead of creating new ones:

```
private static JAXBContext analystContext;
private static JAXBContext commentatorContext;
```

---

```
if (analystContext == null)
    analystContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Analyst.class);
if (commentatorContext == null)
    commentatorContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Commentator.class);
```

And consequently you also need different `Unmarshaller`s created from them:

```
Unmarshaller analystUnmarshaller = analystContext.createUnmarshaller();
Unmarshaller commentatorUnmarshaller = commentatorContext.createUnmarshaller();
```

Then you are able to unmarshal the same XML content to different root classes:

```
String xml = "<Author> <id>1</id> <name>A</name> <title>B</title> <address>C</address></Author>";
Analyst analyst = (Analyst) analystUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));
Commentator commentator = (Commentator) commentatorUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));
```

Comment: From I known, `JAXBContext` is a high Java Object, we can't create too many instances as the performance issue.

Comment: @ChaoJiang Yes, a `JAXBContent` is a big object and `JAXBContext.newInstance(...) takes quite a long time to execute. Therefore you should keep these `JAXBObject` instances in `static` variables and reuse them instead of creating new ones.

Comment: @ChaoJiang I have improved the answer according to the comments above.

Answer (score 1):

Just find a quick way to do this:

1. Register the pojo.

`JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Analyst.class, Commentator.class);`

2. Handle the input. I'm convert the str-xml to StreamSource.

```java
String xml = "<Author> <id>1</id> <name>A</name> <title>B</title> <address>C</address></Author>";
StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));
```

3. Create the Unmarshaller.

`Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();`

4. (important) When you unmarshal the data, give the second paramter (which class you want to unmarshal)

`JAXBElement<Analyst> unmarshal = unmarshaller.unmarshal(source, Analyst.class);`

And then, get what you want:

`Analyst analyst = unmarshal.getValue();`

5. If need another pojo.(Note that `unmarshaller` & `source` can't re-use in a method )

`JAXBElement<Commentator> unmarshal2 = unmarshaller2.unmarshal(source2, Commentator.class);`

And then:

`Commentator com = unmarshal2.getValue();`

No error report and result is correct.